# Macro PowerPoint SlideShow not auto-advancing when run from external VBS

Tags: vba, vbscript, powerpoint

Using a VBS run from a Windows Scheduled Task, I'm automating the start of a PPTM (macro-enabled) slideshow. With the PPTM already open, the VBS calls an "Init" sub of the PPTM. The "Init" sub successfully runs the slideshow (via SlideShowSettings.Run), but the slideshow doesn't auto-advance using the transition timings in the PPTM. Maybe this is a security thing. Maybe I need to set-executionpolicy unrestricted in the folder where the PPTM is? Thoughts?

Comment: Oops, set-executionpolicy is for PowerShell, and I'm only using Windows Based Script Host

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm also using a class module to use the App_SlideShowNextSlide event. I'm instantiating the class module application reference in the original Init sub, but before I wire up this reference (TheEventClassModuleInstance.App = Application) to start the event listening, I'm looping through the slides setting:

```
Dim TheSlidesCounter As Integer
    For TheSlidesCounter = Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Count To 1 Step -1     Presentations.Item(1).Slides(TheSlidesCounter).SlideShowTransition.AdvanceOnTime = msoTrue
    Next
```